# *.exe is not a valid win32 application on win xp after download update 3

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

i have download update 3 for visual studio 2012 and create a c++ hello world application using .NetFrameWork 2.0 (choose from the up choices at creation time)
but when i click at the project properties at 'frame work and references' it display:
'targeted frame work: .NetFrameWork,Version:4.0'
so why the .net frame work version doesn't change ?

then i change the :
'platform toolset' from Visual Studio 2012 (v110) to Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)

and create a setup project for it.
but after install it on windows xp the application said that
"*.exe is not a valid win32 application" why ??

my computer the i try to install the application on it is :
x86 , windows xp sp3 , .NetFrameWork 2.0

Comment: I thing you are trying to run 64bit app in 32bit OS WinXP

Comment: Why is this tagged as c++?

Comment: no i have compile the application for x86

Comment: your 'hello world' application implies this isn't the case but I recently ran into this issue and the cause was a DLL the application was using was compiled without the v110_xp toolset...

Comment: C++/CLI doesn't support multi-targeting.  Changing the platform toolset to v110_xp is only meaningful for C++ projects.

Comment: the project that i have created is a 'Empty Project' Type
and add this line of code 'cout<<"hello"<<endl'